# Laravel - using route name in another route

Tags: laravel

I am trying to use named route in another route like this, but it doesnt work.

```
Route::get('/home', ['as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'HomeController@index']);
Route::post(route('home'), '.....');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `route('home', [], false)` in this case. Third parameter `false` here is to use relative path instead of absolute (default set to `true`):

```
public function route($name, $parameters = array(), $absolute = true);
```

Comment: How to use it in the group? I mean, that when i use this in group, the group prefix will be here, so if the prefix is 'user' and to route is 'login', it will generate '/user/login', but when the route is in the same group, it will be '/user/user/login'.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel could do this for you by using a *RESTful Resource Controller* and allow GET and STORE (to match your example with GET and POST ->http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/controllers)

```
Route::resource('photo', 'PhotoController', ['only' => ['index', 'store']]);
```

Run `php artisan route:list` to see the names of the routes. Or a group of routes (http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing):

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'admin'], function()
{
    Route::get('home', ['as' => 'admin.home.index', 'uses' => 'HomeController@index']);
    Route::get('castle', ['as' => 'admin.castle', 'uses' => 'HomeController@castle']);
});
```